# sending and receiving DatagramPackets not working properly

Tags: java, networking, udp

Working on small video game multiplayer. First player is server and second is a client. I have 2 methods networkSend() and networkRecive() on both client and server. If I only use on server networkReceive() and on client networkSend() than I can see my ships moving. But if I use them both on server and client than I can't move none of the ships. Seems like networkRecieve() waits for respond I guess. How to make them both to work?

First player and Second player contain pretty much same code

```
 // network variables
String ip;
InetAddress address = null;
byte[] buf = new byte[256];
int port = 5001;
DatagramSocket socket = null;
DatagramPacket packet = null;

public Board() {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    craft = new Craft();
    enemy = new Enemy();

    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();

 // DatagramSocket socketS;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(5001);
        System.out.println("Socket created on "+ port + " port");
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Starting server...");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    craft.move();
   // enemy.move();

    networkReceive();
    // if networkSend() is commented than it works 
    networkSend();

    repaint();  
}


private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        craft.keyPressed(e);
    }
}

  public void networkSend(){

    // Serialize to a byte array
    try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ObjectOutputStream oo;
                oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
                oo.writeObject(craft);

                oo.flush();
                oo.close();

                byte[] bufCar = bStream.toByteArray();
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bufCar, bufCar.length, address, port);
                socket.send(packet);

    } catch (IOException e) {   
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}


  public void networkReceive() {


    try {

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                System.out.println("Printing buf="+buf+" and socket "+socket);
                socket.receive(packet);

                 byte[] data = packet.getData();
                    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                        enemy = (Enemy) is.readObject();
                       System.out.println("Enemy x="+enemy.getX()+" and y="+enemy.getY());
                        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                        port    = packet.getPort();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Would make sense to have sends and receives in separate threads so that those calls do not block the whole program? It's either that or a very carefully synchronized sends and receives, which is theoretically still possible, but you would have to change the order between the server and the client to ensure that when one is sending, the other one is receiving, and vice versa.

Comment: I guess thread is a way to go then.